# FullCalendar:Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

i've been getting this error for modal pop up 
the Error :

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.eventClick ((index):134)
>       at t.publiclyTrigger (fullcalendar.min.js:10)
>       at e.publiclyTrigger (fullcalendar.min.js:9)
>       at e.handleClick (fullcalendar.min.js:8)
>       at HTMLAnchorElement. (fullcalendar.min.js:7)
>       at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-1.12.4.js:5226)
>       at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery-1.12.4.js:4878)

here's my index.chtm :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div id="calender"></div>


<div id="myModal" class="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span id="eventTitle"></span></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p id="pDetails"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />


@section scripts{
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var events = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/conge/getConges",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                        events.push({
                            title: v.Subject,
                            description: v.Description,
                            start: moment(v.DateDebut),
                            end: v.DateFin != null ? moment(v.DateFin) : null,
                            color: v.themecolor,
                            allDay: v.IsFullDay
                        });
                    })

                    GenerateCalender(events);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert('failed');
                }
            })

            function GenerateCalender(events) {
                $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
                $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                    contentHeight: 400,
                    defaultDate: new Date(),
                    timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                    },
                    eventLimit: true,
                    eventColor: '#378006',
                    events: events,
                    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view)
                    {

                        $('#myModal #eventTitle').text(calEvent.title);
                        var $description = $('<div/>');
                        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Start:</b>' + calEvent.start.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                        if (calEvent.end != null) {
                            $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>End:</b>' + calEvent.end.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));
                        }
                        $description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Description:</b>' + calEvent.description));
                        $('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($description);

                        $('#myModal').modal();

                    }
                })
            }
        })
    </script>
}
```

[Solved-updated]

Comment: Did you load Bootstrap's javascript file ?

Comment: @Treast how ? i added all the links mentioned

Comment: The `modal` you are using are from Bootstrap. You need to include it in your project. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-javascript

Comment: yes when i added the missing libraries it worked but also i had to remove from class="class fade"

Comment: @Treast thank you very much :D

Comment: You're welcome, enjoy ;) !

Comment: "[Solved-updated]"...don't write this in your question. Put your question back the way it was, and instead write an _Answer_ , then people can compare and contrast the fix with your original code. Right now the post is not useful because the problem stated in the question can't be reproduced from the code shown. You are allowed to answer your own questions, and also to accept your own answer...and then people can vote on it as well :-).

Comment: OH thanks for the advice i will make sure to put it as intended the next time :)